# How to validate an e-mail address in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, validation, email, nsregularexpression

Does anyone know how to validate an e-mail address in Swift? I found this code:

```
- (BOOL) validEmail:(NSString*) emailString {

    if([emailString length]==0){
        return NO;
    }

    NSString *regExPattern = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

    NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:regExPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    NSUInteger regExMatches = [regEx numberOfMatchesInString:emailString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [emailString length])];

    NSLog(@"%i", regExMatches);
    if (regExMatches == 0) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

but I can't translate it to Swift.

Comment: translation should be straightforward.  what part is giving you problems?

Comment: The problem was "    NSRegularExpression *regEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:regExPattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
"

Comment: Don't forget to pray that none of your users has one of the new top level domains. E.g. `.coffee`

Comment: The regexp is not good. Too restrictive. Use "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$" instead

Comment: @Antzi: I checked with "someone@gmail" and your regex returned true.

Comment: Regexes don't work for validating that users have entered their e-mail address. The only 100% correct way is to send an activation e-mail. See: [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/)

Comment: This is a fascinating QA.  **It's almost certainly the "most wrong" QA on the whole site.**  The currently #1 answer with *600 votes* (what?!) is absolutely, totally, wrong in every possible way (every individual line is completely wrong, and every concept and idea is wrong ........ !!!)  Many of the other highly voted answers are either "completely wrong", "extremely shoody", or, plain broken and don't even compile.  Further, while the nature of this Q calls for "elite regex engineering" many answers (highly voted!) feature appalling regex engineering. It's a really interesting QA!! Why??

Comment: I agree with everything Fattie says - the difference between "good enough" and "near perfect": github.com/dhoerl/EmailAddressFinder. That said, I wrote a Mac project that constructs a regex, where each step in the construction references appropriate RFCs. It correctly processes several test suites of "edge cases" meant to trap incorrect regexes. But, as he said, it will allow "x@x" since that address is compliant with the specs. There is also a GitHub project (can't find the link) that offers a long long list of email servers, and probably has 99% coverage of ones you'd need to test against.

Comment: Amazingly this QA now has ***eight hundred votes on a totally, absolutely, completely wrong answer!***  This is the "famously wrong answer" on SO.

Answer (score 895, accepted):

I would use [`NSPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate):

```swift
func isValidEmail(_ email: String) -> Bool {        
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

    let emailPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailPred.evaluate(with: email)
}
```

*for versions of Swift earlier than 3.0:*

```swift
func isValidEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

    let emailPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailPred.evaluate(with: email)
}
```

*for versions of Swift earlier than 1.2:*

```swift
func isValidEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

    if let emailPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx) {
        return emailPred.evaluateWithObject(email)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)` be a lot more simpler and readable? Comparing to `== true` is a bit like Javascript.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, in case if you don't want to debug it or leave logs. Actually you can write it with one row

Comment: @Sulthan but you are right about `== true`, habit from Javascript :)

Comment: @MaximShoustin Writing `if (booleanCondition) { return true } else { return false }` is a bad habit in most languages, including javascript . If you want to add a log or have a value to inspect during debugging, you should assign that boolean to a variable and return that variable.  Also mind the semicolons which are not written in Swift.

Comment: This is a really nice example. However, it should be worth nothing though that with the advent of all the new TLDs such as .pizza or .google that the final part of the regex needs adjusting.

Comment: It doesn't check if there is an extension available, a@a is already OK :(

Comment: @MaximShoustin
Try entering something like xyz@xy and still it returns true. But this is wrong. Using Swift 1.2. and using your above code. that failed

just replace the emailRegEx with
 let emailRegEx = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"

And it will work fine even for xyz@xy and will return false

Comment: it accepts emails starting with a dot, however its a RegEx issue

Comment: this does not validate for test@test...com

Comment: This doesn't detect email.@invalid.com or email@.invalid.com. The answer below from @alexcristea does

Comment: `qwe@qwe@qwe.qwe` is OK too :(

Comment: I have to add start and end of regular expression like ^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$ other wise it is also allowing abc^asd@da.com

Comment: this let's a user accidentally enter in .con instead of .com which is a very common mistake in the app I wrote ...

Comment: @LloydRochester well, this is not common case. `boy@somecomp.con` is a valid email.

Comment: @MaximShoustin what I meant to really say is beware these answers don't validate top level domains and as such will allow a `.con` email instead of a `.com`. On mobile devices users will make this mistake a lot because the `n` character is close to to the `m`. This will certainly make users confused in say a user signup field where they're expecting an email confirmation.

Comment: It's quite funny that ............ as well as (1) the regex being utterly, totally **incorrect** (2) the regex (even within the context of what it's trying to do) has major **errors** (3) the Swift is **wrong** (4) even setting that aside, the **style** is totally wrong (5) not that it matters given all the rest but it doesn't even mention that you have to **cache** the predicate  ... humorously, (6) there's still **left over code** ("calendar" - what?) from wherever it was copied from.

Comment: None of the provided answers, including the accepted one, support IDNs - international domain names.

Comment: doesn't pass all the tests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297420/list-of-email-addresses-that-can-be-used-to-test-a-javascript-validation-script

Comment: @Fattie funny enough, yours is also a wrong suggestion, easily fooled by links that are not email addresses: "mailto://www.google.com"

Comment: hi @Jano (1) funnily enough, I don't know what you mean?  (Are you referring to the comment about  "email validation swift") (2) my answer is not a suggestion, it's the correct answer :)  (3) you can easily test it with 'mailto://www.google.com'. Cheers

Comment: @Fattie Apologies for the confusion. I was probably referring to the preamble data detector solution you posted. Other than that, your code is a reasonable answer.

Comment: It is I who should apologize!  Cheers ...

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,64}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Comment: Lots of funny comments, but how about providing a better answer instead, if this is totally incorrect?

Answer (score 121):

Editing, updated for Swift 3:

```
func validateEmail(enteredEmail:String) -> Bool {

    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)
    return emailPredicate.evaluate(with: enteredEmail)

}
```

Original answer for Swift 2:

```
func validateEmail(enteredEmail:String) -> Bool {

    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)
    return emailPredicate.evaluateWithObject(enteredEmail)

}
```

It's working fine.

Comment: the first with a valid regex. the others validate aa@aach to true

Comment: @netshark1000, only with upvotes, any answer will be on top. :)

Comment: NSRegularExpression is simpler to use than NSPredicate

Comment: It does not handle the two dots condition after the domain name. try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53441176/5032981

Comment: @AzikAbdullah If you enter 'abc@gmail..com' then also it will validate

Comment: In my unit test this validation failed with 'test@.com.so'

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,64}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Answer (score 120):

As a `String` class extension

**SWIFT 4**

```
extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        // here, `try!` will always succeed because the pattern is valid
        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$", options: .caseInsensitive)
        return regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count)) != nil
    }
}
```

Usage

```
if "rdfsdsfsdfsd".isValidEmail() {

}
```

Comment: `countElements` is now `count`

Comment: xxx@yyy  return true?

Comment: Same as Cullen SUN, foo@bar return true.

Comment: Getting a error 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' and 'Use of unresolved identifier countElements'. I'm using Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: user@host without .tld is also a valid email address, e.g. root@localhost

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Comment: replace characters.count with self.count

Comment: if xyz@abc.com is your preference then this regex should work. `"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+]+@[A-Za-z0-9.]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"` testing in my project.

Comment: In my unit test this validation failed with 'test@.com.so'

Comment: For anyone googling here this answer is completely, totally, wrong.

Comment: Regex is invalid here... this is wrong.

Answer (score 84):

If you are looking for a clean and simple solution to do this, you should take a look at https://github.com/nsagora/validation-components.

It contains an email validation predicate which is easy integrate in your code:

```
let email = "test@example.com"
let rule = EmailValidationPredicate()
let isValidEmail = rule.evaluate(with: email)
```

---

Behind the hood it uses the RFC 5322 reg ex (http://emailregex.com):

```
let regex = "(?:[\\p{L}0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[\\p{L}0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}" +
    "~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\" +
    "x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[\\p{L}0-9](?:[a-" +
    "z0-9-]*[\\p{L}0-9])?\\.)+[\\p{L}0-9](?:[\\p{L}0-9-]*[\\p{L}0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5" +
    "]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-" +
    "9][0-9]?|[\\p{L}0-9-]*[\\p{L}0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21" +
    "-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about emailregex.com. It is awesome!

Comment: Finally, one that filters email.@.email.com

Comment: it's working with exact -- abcd@abcd.com . it's not validate abc@abc

Comment: Ah, Finally.. :D

Comment: This seems to allow a one character domain suffix which is technically legal but all of those are held by the registrar so in practice it will always be invalid.

Comment: This worked great for me once I added a ^ between the " and ( at the beginning!

Answer (score 75):

(Preamble. Be aware that in some cases, you can now use this solution built-in to iOS: https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/11/02/email-validation-swift/ )

---

### The only solution:

1 - it avoids the **horrific regex mistakes** often seen in example code

2 - it does **NOT** allow ridiculous emails such as "x@x"

(If for some reason you need a solution that allows nonsense strings such as 'x@x', use another solution.)

3 - the code is **extremely understandable**

4 - it is KISS, reliable, and ***tested to destruction on commercial apps with enormous numbers of users***

5 - the **predicate** is a global, as **Apple says** it must be

```
let __firstpart = "[A-Z0-9a-z]([A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]{0,30}[A-Z0-9a-z])?"
let __serverpart = "([A-Z0-9a-z]([A-Z0-9a-z-]{0,30}[A-Z0-9a-z])?\\.){1,5}"
let __emailRegex = __firstpart + "@" + __serverpart + "[A-Za-z]{2,8}"
let __emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", __emailRegex)

extension String {
    func isEmail() -> Bool {
        return __emailPredicate.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}

extension UITextField {
    func isEmail() -> Bool {
        return self.text?.isEmail() ?? false
    }
}
```

It's that easy.

### Explanation for anyone new to regex:

In this description, "OC" means ordinary character - a letter or a digit.

__firstpart ... has to **start and end** with an OC. For the characters in the **middle** you can have **certain** characters such as underscore, but the **start and end** have to be an OC.  (However, it's **ok** to have only one OC and that's it, for example: j@blah.com)

__serverpart ... You have **sections** like "blah." which **repeat**. (Example, mail.city.fcu.edu.) The sections have to **start and end** with an OC, but in the **middle** you can also have a **dash** "-". It's **OK** to have a section which is just **one** OC. (Example, w.campus.edu)  You can have up to five sections, you **have to** have one.  Finally the **TLD** (such as .com) is strictly 2 to 8 in **size** . (Obviously, just change the "8" as preferred by your support department.)

---

### IMPORTANT !

**You MUST keep the predicate as a global, do not build it every time.**

Note that this is **the first thing Apple mentions about the whole issue** in the docs.

Suggestions which do not cache the predicate are non-starters.

---

### Non-english alphabets

Naturally, if you deal with non-english alphabets, adjust appropriately.

Comment: Does it support new TLDs like .engineer?

Comment: With regards to point (4): how did you test with a lot of users? Did you track the users, that could not sign up with the commercial apps, because the regex did prevent them from using their email address? The only "reasonable" should be, what the spec (RFC) specifies or if this can not be achieved, then something that is more relaxed, but covers everything from the spec. If the users are not allowed to enter x@x, they will enter some garbage@example.com which will pass your/any regex.

Comment: This is an awesome answer. I was trying to validate the email id as the user types and toggle the enabled status of a button. With other regexes, the button gets enabled when i type aaa@aaa and then disabled when I add a '.' . This works as expected in my case.

Comment: Hi @Fattie, could you provide us a link where Apple explains that the predicate must be global? Thanks

Comment: Warning. This doesn’t work with IDNs (international domain names)

Comment: hi @andbi .  It works absolutely perfectly with "international" domain names.  Could you give a clear example of what you mean?

Comment: @Fattie "user@домен.рф” for example. While absolutely valid, it doesn’t pass the validation.

Comment: @andbi - that's a very reasonable point. the example given is (I'm sorry) only for english-language alphabets.  you're definitely right that in many situations, the programmer would add the foreign alphabet.  that is a top point, thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: Email addresses can't start or end with dots (unless if they're in quotes) yet the link provided in your answer validates emails that start and end with dots. What am I missing?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link to the docs for where Apple states that an instance of `NSPredicate` must be global? I can't find it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate).

Answer (score 39):

## Simplest way in Swift 5

```swift
extension String {
    var isValidEmail: Bool {
        NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}").evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

**Example**

```swift
"kenmueller0@gmail.com".isValidEmail
```

**returns...**

```swift
true
```

Comment: what is the point of repeating the repeated answer? which doesn't depend on any Swift 5 features

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Answer (score 34):

Here is a fuse of the two most up-voted answer with a basic correct enough regex: a String extension using predicate so you can call string.isEmail

```
    extension String {
        var isEmail: Bool {
           let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,20}"            
           let emailTest  = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
           return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: .evaluateWithObject(self) has been changed to .evaluate(with: self)

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,20}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Comment: So many issues indeed terrible code. Ask ChatGPT for the correct answer.

Comment: @NicolasManzini ChatGPT gave me this same answer! :D

Answer (score 25):

I would suggest using it as an extension of String:

```
extension String {    
    public var isEmail: Bool {
        let dataDetector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)

        let firstMatch = dataDetector?.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length))

        return (firstMatch?.range.location != NSNotFound && firstMatch?.url?.scheme == "mailto")
    }

    public var length: Int {
        return self.characters.count
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
if "hodor@gameofthrones.com".isEmail { // true
    print("Hold the Door")
}
```

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Comment: Update Swift 4:   
extension String {
public var isEmail: Bool {
    let dataDetector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let firstMatch = dataDetector?.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: count))
    return (firstMatch?.range.location != NSNotFound && firstMatch?.url?.scheme == "mailto")
}

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! 
While other answers resolve the validation of emails in english letters, this beast validates emails in Arabic and other languages as well. Well done!

Comment: This is easily fooled: "mailto://www.google.com".isEmail == true, but it’s not an email.

Answer (score 15):

This is the updated version for Swift 2.0 - 2.2

```
 var isEmail: Bool {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$", options: .CaseInsensitive)
        return regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) != nil
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: foo@bar returns true ?!

Comment: validates aa@aach to true

Comment: That's because the RFC validates these email adresses to true ;)

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Comment: it's really wrong / poor to not cache the predicate. it's the first thing Apple says about the issue in the doco. a glaring mistake made by most of the answers on the page.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a method based on `rangeOfString`:

```
class func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let range = testStr.rangeOfString(emailRegEx, options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
    return range != nil
}
```

Note: updated TLD length.

Here is the definitive RegEx for email as per RFC 5322, note that this is best not used because it only checks the basic syntax of email addresses and does not check is the top level domain exists.

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*
  |  "(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]
      |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")
@ (?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
  |  \[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
       (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:
          (?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]
          |  \\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)
     \])
```

See [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) for more complete information on email RegExs.

Note that no escaping as required by a language such as Objective-C or Swift.

Comment: the emailRegEx you use is just plain wrong. It only allow for TLDs 2 to 4 characters long, while domains like `.engineer` exists.

Comment: Understood, I am not defending my answer but the level of the edit. Add a comment as above, down-vote, point to a better answer, add your own answer. It is not appropriate to substantially change an answer. I have added the diffusive RegEx for completeness.

Comment: Why oh why not just delete the answer then?  *What possible reason* could there be to keep it here?

Comment: Oh god, so many answers here are wrong the same way. The regex should be enclosed in ^...$, otherwise it will match the regex anywhere in the input string!

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,64}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of right answers here, but many of the "regex" are incomplete and it can happen that an email like: "name@domain" results a valid email, but it is not. Here the complete solution:

```
extension String {

    var isEmailValid: Bool {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])", options: .CaseInsensitive)
            return regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) != nil
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work properly, it lets you add spaces after domain.

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Comment: @Fattie argue your statement. Your comment is very useless, suggest an improvement, propose a fix. Saying completely wrong is very stupid and underlies a close mentality

Comment: It instantly and completely fails the most trivial and obvious tests.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer use an extension for that. Besides, this url http://emailregex.com can help you to test if regex is correct. In fact, the site offers differents implementations for some programming languages. I share my implementation for **Swift 3**.

```
extension String {
    func validateEmail() -> Bool {
        let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: there are a few problems .. you can have, for example .. blah@.abc with a weird dot there

Answer (score 7):

This a new version for **"THE REASONABLE SOLUTION"** by @Fattie, tested on Swift 4.1 in a new file called `String+Email.swift`:

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    private static let __firstpart = "[A-Z0-9a-z]([A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]{0,30}[A-Z0-9a-z])?"
    private static let __serverpart = "([A-Z0-9a-z]([A-Z0-9a-z-]{0,30}[A-Z0-9a-z])?\\.){1,5}"
    private static let __emailRegex = __firstpart + "@" + __serverpart + "[A-Za-z]{2,6}"

    public var isEmail: Bool {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", type(of:self).__emailRegex)
        return predicate.evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

So its usage is simple:

```
let str = "mail@domain.com"
if str.isEmail {
    print("\(str) is a valid e-mail address")
} else {
    print("\(str) is not a valid e-mail address")
}
```

I simply don't like to add a `func` to the `String` objects, as being an e-mail address is inherent to them (or not). So a `Bool` property would fit better than a `func`, from my understanding.

Comment: But here the NSPredicate is no more global.

Comment: @LucasTegliabue this is a more than two year old answer, it could be wrong nowadays.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that in your snippet the NSPredicate is no global. NSPredicate has the same lifecycle of the String instance, so is not global at all, or I am loosing something?

Answer (score 7):

Make a simple test for a `@` and `.` and send a confirmation email.

Consider this:

- Half of the world uses non-ASCII characters.
- Regexes are slow and complex. Btw check at least for char/letter/Unicode range, not az.
- You can’t afford full validation because RFC rules and [corresponding regex](https://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt) are too complex.

I’m using this basic check:

```swift
// similar to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/78372/22077
import Foundation

/**
 Checks that
 - length is 254 or less (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/574698/412916)
 - there is a @ which is not the first character
 - there is a . after the @
 - there are at least 4 characters after the @
*/
func isValidEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
    guard email.count <= 254 else { 
        return false 
    }
    let pos = email.lastIndex(of: "@") ?? email.endIndex
    return (pos != email.startIndex)
        && ((email.lastIndex(of: ".") ?? email.startIndex) > pos) 
        && (email[pos...].count > 4)
}

print(isValidEmail(email: "アシッシュ@ビジネス.コム")) // true
```

Note that

- It is considerably faster than regex and NSDataDetector.
- It correctly reports the following as valid:

```
Håkan.Söderström@malmö.se"
punnycode@XN--0ZWM56D.XN--HGBK6AJ7F53BBA"
试@例子.测试.مثال.آزمایشی"
foo.bar+something@blah.com"
m@foo.co.uk
```

- It incorrectly reports the following as invalid –because they are actually valid but likely the product of a user error:

```
a @ b
a@b
```

Related:

- [How far should one take e-mail address validation?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation)
- online email checker: https://isemail.info/

Answer (score 5):

For swift 2.1: this works correctly with email foo@bar

```
extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}", options: .CaseInsensitive)
            return regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) != nil
        } catch {
                return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. As far as I understand it you could even omit the 'A-Z' (capital letters) since you have the option .CaseInsensitive set anyway...

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Answer (score 5):

Use of Swift 4.2

```
extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(((([a-zA-Z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])+(\\.([a-zA-Z]|\\d|[!#\\$%&'\\*\\+\\-\\/=\\?\\^_`{\\|}~]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])+)*)|((\\x22)((((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(([\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x7f]|\\x21|[\\x23-\\x5b]|[\\x5d-\\x7e]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])|(\\([\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0d-\\x7f]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}]))))*(((\\x20|\\x09)*(\\x0d\\x0a))?(\\x20|\\x09)+)?(\\x22)))@((([a-zA-Z]|\\d|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])|(([a-zA-Z]|\\d|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])([a-zA-Z]|\\d|-|\\.|_|~|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])*([a-zA-Z]|\\d|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])))\\.)+(([a-zA-Z]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])|(([a-zA-Z]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])([a-zA-Z]|\\d|-|_|~|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])*([a-zA-Z]|[\\x{00A0}-\\x{D7FF}\\x{F900}-\\x{FDCF}\\x{FDF0}-\\x{FFEF}])))\\.?$", options: .caseInsensitive)
        return regex?.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) != nil
    }
    func isValidName() -> Bool{
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[\\p{L}\\.]{2,30}(?: [\\p{L}\\.]{2,30}){0,2}$", options: .caseInsensitive)

        return regex?.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count)) != nil
    } }
```

And used

```
if (textField.text?.isValidEmail())! 
    {
      // bla bla
    }
else 
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Apple's [own documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/regexbuilder) for the `RegexBuilder` type (introduced in Swift 5.7) now offers an example of minimal email validation, complete with named component capture.

(Copying here for posterity as they sometimes change their examples)

```swift
let word = OneOrMore(.word)
let emailPattern = Regex {
    Capture {
        ZeroOrMore {
            word
            "."
        }
        word
    }
    "@"
    Capture {
        word
        OneOrMore {
            "."
            word
        }
    }
}

let text = "My email is my.name@example.com."
if let match = text.firstMatch(of: emailPattern) {
    let (wholeMatch, name, domain) = match.output
    // wholeMatch is "my.name@example.com"
    // name is "my.name"
    // domain is "example.com"
}
```

Despite this question already having too many answers, I felt this was worth sharing since it:

1. Uses the latest Swift APIs
2. Does not overcomplicate the regex logic (a trap for email validation)
3. Comes directly from Apple (almost like they *knew*)

Answer (score 2):

@JeffersonBe's answer is close, but returns `true` if the string is "something containing someone@something.com a valid email" which is not what we want.  The following is an extension on String that works well (and allows testing for valid phoneNumber and other data detectors to boot.

```
/// Helper for various data detector matches.
/// Returns `true` iff the `String` matches the data detector type for the complete string.
func matchesDataDetector(type: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType, scheme: String? = nil) -> Bool {
    let dataDetector = try? NSDataDetector(types: type.rawValue)
    guard let firstMatch = dataDetector?.firstMatch(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.reportCompletion, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: length)) else {
        return false
    }
    return firstMatch.range.location != NSNotFound
        // make sure the entire string is an email, not just contains an email
        && firstMatch.range.location == 0
        && firstMatch.range.length == length
        // make sure the link type matches if link scheme
        && (type != .link || scheme == nil || firstMatch.url?.scheme == scheme)
}
/// `true` iff the `String` is an email address in the proper form.
var isEmail: Bool {
    return matchesDataDetector(type: .link, scheme: "mailto")
}
/// `true` iff the `String` is a phone number in the proper form.
var isPhoneNumber: Bool {
    return matchesDataDetector(type: .phoneNumber)
}
/// number of characters in the `String` (required for above).
var length: Int {
    return self.characters.count
}
```

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Comment: "mailto://www.google.com".isEmail == true, but not an email.

Answer (score 2):

Create simple extension:

```
extension NSRegularExpression {

    convenience init(pattern: String) {
        try! self.init(pattern: pattern, options: [])
    }
}

extension String {

    var isValidEmail: Bool {
        return isMatching(expression: NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"))
    }

    //MARK: - Private

    private func isMatching(expression: NSRegularExpression) -> Bool {
        return expression.numberOfMatches(in: self, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: characters.count)) > 0
    }
}
```

Example:

```
"b@bb.pl".isValidEmail //true
"b@bb".isValidEmail //false
```

You can extend following extension to anything you need: `isValidPhoneNumber`, `isValidPassword` etc...

Comment: Note that `NSRange` length property should use `String` `utf16.count` instead of `characters.count`

Answer (score 2):

Majority of the above regex examples fail to catch error when there are even basic problems with emails. For example

1. `h..1@nyu.edu` - consecutive dots
2. `ab1234@.nyu.edu` - dot after @
3. `a.bcdnle12.@email.com` - dot before @
4. `.abc@email.com` - starts with a dot

Here is a string extension I have used that uses regex with tighter rules.

```
extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "^(?!\\.)([A-Z0-9a-z_%+-]?[\\.]?[A-Z0-9a-z_%+-])+@[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,20}(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]{1,15}){0,10}\\.[A-Za-z]{2,20}$"
        let emailPred = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
        return emailPred.evaluate(with: self)
   }
}
```

Here is how we can write test case for it.

```
XCTAssertFalse("ab1234@.nyu.edu".isValidEmail())
XCTAssertTrue("valid_email@email.com".isValidEmail())
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a library designed for input validations and one of the "modules" allows you to easily validate a bunch of stuff...

For example to validate an email:

```
let emailTrial = Trial.Email
let trial = emailTrial.trial()

if(trial(evidence: "test@test.com")) {
   //email is valid
}
```

[SwiftCop](https://github.com/andresinaka/SwiftCop) is the library... hope it help!

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer @Arsonik answer to Swift 2.2, using less verbose code than other offered solutions:

```
extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$", options: .CaseInsensitive)
        return regex?.firstMatchInString(self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) != nil
    }
}
```

Comment: abcd@a is passing with this regex. You should fix it.

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Answer (score 1):

My only addition to the list of responses would be that for Linux, `NSRegularExpression` does not exist, it's actually `RegularExpression`

```
    func isEmail() -> Bool {

    let patternNormal = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"

    #if os(Linux)
        let regex = try? RegularExpression(pattern: patternNormal, options: .caseInsensitive)
    #else
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: patternNormal, options: .caseInsensitive)
    #endif

    return regex?.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) != nil
```

This compiles successfully on both macOS & Ubuntu.

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension in Swift 3

```
extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

Just use it like this:

```
if yourEmailString.isValidEmail() {
    //code for valid email address
} else {
    //code for not valid email address
}
```

Comment: Changing to use the Regex from alexcristea' answer, it's perfect solution.

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,64}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution with best result for

> Swift 4.x

```
 extension String {

        func validateAsEmail() -> Bool {
            let emailRegEx = "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%\\&‘*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}" +
                "~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\" +
                "x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-" +
                "z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5" +
                "]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-" +
                "9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21" +
            "-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"

            let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", emailRegEx)
            return emailTest.evaluate(with: self)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I improved @Azik answer. I allow more special characters which are allowed by guidelines, as well as return a few extra edge cases as invalid.

The group think going on here to only allow `._%+-` in the local part is not correct per guidelines. See @Anton Gogolev answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address) question or see below:

> The local-part of the email address may use any of these ASCII
>   characters:
>
> - uppercase and lowercase Latin letters `A` to `Z` and `a` to `z`;
> - digits `0` to `9`;
> - special characters `` !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~ ``;
> - dot `.`, provided that it is not the first or last character unless quoted, and provided also that it does not appear consecutively unless quoted (e.g.
>     `John..Doe@example.com` is not allowed but `"John..Doe"@example.com` is
>     allowed);
> - space and `"(),:;<>@[\]` characters are allowed with
>     restrictions (they are only allowed inside a quoted string, as
>     described in the paragraph below, and in addition, a backslash or
>     double-quote must be preceded by a backslash); 
>     comments are allowed
> - with parentheses at either end of the local-part; e.g.
>     `john.smith(comment)@example.com` and `(comment)john.smith@example.com`
>     are both equivalent to `john.smith@example.com`;

The code I use will not allow restricted out of place special characters, but will allow many more options than the majority of answers here. I would prefer more relaxed validation to error on the side of caution.

```
if enteredText.contains("..") || enteredText.contains("@@") 
   || enteredText.hasPrefix(".") || enteredText.hasSuffix(".con"){
       return false
}

let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)     
return emailPredicate.evaluate(with: enteredText)
```

Comment: Thanks for the first part with contains check and return false

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,64}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 4.2** and Xcode 10.1

```
//Email validation
func isValidEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: email)
    if valid {
        valid = !email.contains("Invalid email id")
    }
    return valid
}

//Use like this....
let emailTrimmedString = emailTF.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
if isValidEmail(email: emailTrimmedString!) == false {
   SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view: self, title: "", message: "Please enter valid email")
}
```

If you want to use SharedClass.

```
//This is SharedClass
import UIKit
class SharedClass: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = SharedClass()

//Email validation
func isValidEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: email)
    if valid {
        valid = !email.contains("Invalid email id")
    }
    return valid
}

private override init() {

}
}
```

And call function like this....

```
if SharedClass.sharedInstance. isValidEmail(email: emailTrimmedString!) == false {
   SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view: self, title: "", message: "Please enter correct email")
   //Your code here
} else {
   //Code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an up to date playground compatible version that uses the standard library so you don't have to maintain a regex:

```swift
import Foundation

func isValid(email: String) -> Bool {
  do {
    let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: email.count)
    let matches = detector.matches(in: email, options: .anchored, range: range)
    guard matches.count == 1 else { return false }
    return matches[0].url?.scheme == "mailto"
  } catch {
    return false
  }
}

extension String {
  var isValidEmail: Bool {
    isValid(email: self)
  }
}

let email = "test@mail.com"
isValid(email: email) // prints 'true'
email.isValidEmail // prints 'true'
```

Comment: NSDataDetector solutions are unreliable because they validate strings like: `mailto://www.google.com`, which is not an email.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5.7, with the help of the Regex class, we can validate email addresses in a simple and efficient manner

```
private func isValidEmail(_ email: String) -> Bool {
      guard let emailRegex = try? Regex("[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}")  
      else { return false }
      return email.firstMatch(of: emailRegex) != nil
   }
```

Also we can use a property wrapper to make it more efficient:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct EmailPropertyWrapper {
  private var _value: String
  var wrappedValue: String {
    get { return isValidEmail(_value) ? _value : String() }
    set { _value = newValue }
  }
  
  init(email: String) {
    _value = email
  }

  private func isValidEmail(_ email: String) -> Bool {
      guard let emailRegex = try? Regex("[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}")  
      else { return false }
      return email.firstMatch(of: emailRegex) != nil
   }
}

struct User {
  var name: String
  @EmailPropertyWrapper var email: String
  
  func validateProperty() -> Bool {
    if name.isEmpty || email.isEmpty { return false }
    return true
  }
}

let user = User(name: "Sy", email: .init(email: "wwdc@icloud.com"))

print(user.validateProperty())
```

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,64}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are so many weird top level domain name now, I stop checking the length of the top domain...

Here is what I use:

```
extension String {

    func isEmail() -> Bool {
        let emailRegEx = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$"
        return NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx).evaluateWithObject(self)
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work too...

```
let regex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

func validate(email: String) -> Bool {
    let matches = email.rangeOfString(regex, options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
    if let _ = matches {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Answer (score 0):

And for **Swift 3**:

```
extension String {
    func isValidEmail() -> Bool {
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$", options: .caseInsensitive)
        return regex?.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) != nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Answer (score 0):

Two simple extensions:

```
extension NSRegularExpression {
  convenience init(_ pattern: String) {
    do {
      try self.init(pattern: pattern)
    } catch {
      preconditionFailure("Illegal regular expression: \(pattern).")
    }
  }

  func wholeMatch(_ string: String) -> Bool {
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count)
    guard let match = firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: range) else { return false }
    return range.length == match.range.length
  }
}

extension String {
  var isValidEmail: Bool {
    let __firstpart = "[A-Z0-9a-z]([A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]{0,30}[A-Z0-9a-z])?"
    let __serverpart = "([A-Z0-9a-z]([A-Z0-9a-z-]{0,30}[A-Z0-9a-z])?\\.){1,5}"
    let pattern = __firstpart + "@" + __serverpart + "[A-Za-z]{2,20}"
    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern)
    return regex.wholeMatch(self)
  }
}
```

Why am I doing it?) Despite the huge number of answers, I have not found a suitable one for me. Therefore, I made up my answer, collecting all the best.

So, I used a pretty good regex from Fattie's answer. A small improvement is only in the length of the top-level domain (among the currently registered ones, the length is 18 characters.) And the second and main reason is incorrect processing of special characters like № and ™ by NSPredicate. It seems that such characters are not processed according to unicode, but rather according to similar graphemes. For example, № is recognized as "No". NSRegularExpression lacks this drawback.

Yes, I do not take into account emails that are not in English.
And I have not found clear information on why it is worth putting NSRegularExpression in the global. But you can adjust appropriately)

Answer (score -1):

**Perfect Regex like Google Email**

```
"^[A-Z0-9a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
```

Comment: whoever vote out my answer, kindly check your knowledge. I have applied this regex in many code and my friends of mine is using this regex and it works great..Before vote out my answer kindly do comment and let me know what is wrong with this regex.

Comment: I think I can answer: Your regex is to simple and doesn't match the RFC.
For example, emails can have quotes and even spaces in the first part!
Look at https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/

Comment: Sorry, brother, I think you should check google email validation, there is no way to add Space in the first part of an email, and if my regex is wrong then why doesn't anyone post write and perfect regex.

Comment: According to the RFC 5322, "Hello world!"@example.com is a valid email.
Indeed, it is almost impossible to make a valid regex.
Not every mail provider will stick to google email validation.

Comment: Thats what I want to listen, and thats why I mentioned in bold heading that above regex is like Google. Thanks

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can have extension for optional text of UITextField:

how to use:

```
if  emailTextField.text.isEmailValid() {
      print("email is valid")
}else{
      print("wrong email address")
}
```

extension:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    func isEmailValid() -> Bool{
        guard let email = self else { return false }
        let emailPattern = "[A-Za-z-0-9.-_]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}"
        do{
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: emailPattern, options: .caseInsensitive)
            let foundPatters = regex.numberOfMatches(in: email, options: .anchored, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: email.count))
            if foundPatters > 0 {
                return true
            }
        }catch{
            //error
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that NSRange length property should use String utf16.count instead of characters.count

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who is still looking for an answer to this, please have a look at the following framework;

[ATGValidator](https://github.com/altayer-digital/ATGValidator)

It is a rule based validation framework, which handles most of the validations out of box. And top it all, it has `form validator` which supports validation of multiple textfields at the same time.

For validating an email string, use the following;

```
"abcd.hhs@some.com".satisfyAll(rules: [StringRegexRule.email]).status
```

If you want to validate an email from textfield, try below code;

```
textfield.validationRules = [StringRegexRule.email]
textfield.validationHandler = { result in
    // This block will be executed with relevant result whenever validation is done.
    print(result.status, result.errors)
}
// Below line is to manually trigger validation.
textfield.validateTextField()
```

If you want to validate it while typing in textfield or when focus is changed to another field, add one of the following lines;

```
textfield.validateOnInputChange(true)
// or
textfield.validateOnFocusLoss(true)
```

Please check the readme file at the [link](https://github.com/altayer-digital/ATGValidator) for more use cases.

Answer (score -2):

I like to create extension

```
   extension String {

func isValidateEmail() -> Bool {
    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)
    return emailPredicate.evaluate(with: self)
}

}
```

usage:

```
if emailid.text!.isValidateEmail() == false(){
 //do what ever you want if string is not matched.

}
```

Comment: So many issues here. The `{2,64}` at the end only applies to the last `[A-Za-z]`. This regex fails on valid emails and it passes invalid emails.

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5**

```
 func isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: String) -> Bool {

 var returnValue = true
 let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z.-_]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}"

 do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: emailRegEx)
        let nsString = emailAddressString as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: emailAddressString, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: nsString.length))

        if results.count == 0
        {
            returnValue = false
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        returnValue = false
    }

    return  returnValue
}
```

Then:

```
let validEmail = isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: "your@email.com")
print(validEmail)
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a very simple way available in current Swiftmailer. Most of the other answers are old and reinvent the wheel.

As per Swiftmailer documentation:
https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html#quick-reference

```
use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\RFCValidation;

$validator = new EmailValidator();
$validator->isValid("example@example.com", new RFCValidation()); //true
```

This is by far the simplest and most robust approach, imo. Just install via Composer the Egulias\EmailValidator library which should already be brought in as a dependency of SwiftMailer anyway.