# how to check the entered email is in email format

Tags: ios, regex, swift, email

How to check whether the entered email is in coorect form. Like somename@gmail.com or any.

here my code.I tried but i am getting error in my if statement

```
import UIKit

extension String {
    func matchPattern(patStr:String)->Bool {
        var isMatch:Bool = false
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: patStr, options: [.CaseInsensitive])
            let result = regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count))

            if (result != nil)
            {
                isMatch = true
            }
        }
        catch {
            isMatch = false
        }
        return isMatch
    }
}

class RegisterVC: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var EmailField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var LocationField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameField: UITextField!



    @IBOutlet weak var passWordField: UITextField!



    @IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
@IBAction func SignUpBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        let Email:NSString = EmailField.text!
        let Location:NSString = LocationField.text!
        let username:NSString = userNameField.text!
        let password:NSString = passWordField.text!
        let confirm_password:NSString = confirmPasswordField.text!

        if (Email.matchPattern("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$")==true)
        {
            print("this is e-mail!")
        }

        else if ( Email.isEqualToString("") || Location.isEqualToString("") || username.isEqualToString("") || password.isEqualToString("") || confirm_password.isEqualToString("") ) {


            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "All Field Are Mnditory.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                print("Settings")
            }

            alertController.addAction(DestructiveAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)



        } else if ( !password.isEqual(confirm_password) ) {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Password Din't Match.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                print("Password Din't Match")
            }

            alertController.addAction(DestructiveAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }




        print("login sucess")
}
```

what i need is, if any user start tying the email id is in wrong format, i need to show alert.

Thanks

Comment: *" i am getting error in my if statement"* is a useless problem description. Which if statement and what error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998409/email-phone-validation-in-swift/27998447#27998447

Comment: There really is no good way to validate an email address other than actually contacting the host and seeing if it will accept the email. See this article: [I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope it helps:

```
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {

    print("validate emilId: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    let result = emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
    return result

}
```

In your code:

```
import UIKit

extension String {
    func matchPattern(patStr:String)->Bool {
        var isMatch:Bool = false
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: patStr, options: [.CaseInsensitive])
            let result = regex.firstMatchInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, characters.count))

            if (result != nil)
            {
                isMatch = true
            }
        }
        catch {
            isMatch = false
        }
        return isMatch
    }
}

class RegisterVC: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var EmailField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var LocationField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameField: UITextField!



    @IBOutlet weak var passWordField: UITextField!



    @IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordField: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {

    print("validate emilId: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    let result = emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
    return result

}

@IBAction func SignUpBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
        let Email:NSString = EmailField.text!
        let Location:NSString = LocationField.text!
        let username:NSString = userNameField.text!
        let password:NSString = passWordField.text!
        let confirm_password:NSString = confirmPasswordField.text!

        if isValidEmail(Email) == true{
        {
            print("this is e-mail!")
        }

        else if ( Email.isEqualToString("") || Location.isEqualToString("") || username.isEqualToString("") || password.isEqualToString("") || confirm_password.isEqualToString("") ) {


            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "All Field Are Mnditory.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                print("Settings")
            }

            alertController.addAction(DestructiveAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)



        } else if ( !password.isEqual(confirm_password) ) {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Password Din't Match.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                print("Password Din't Match")
            }

            alertController.addAction(DestructiveAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }




        print("login sucess")
}
```

Comment: i just copy your func method , but it not shwoing when i enter an unformat email??

Comment: its ok , but how can i call this method inside my signupbutton pressd method

Comment: You need to expand the regex a little `emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,15}"` - A lot of domain endings now end in more than 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
-(BOOL)isValidEmailAddress:(NSString *)email
{
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES; 
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@.+\\.[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString:laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:email];

}
```

Swift version

```
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {

println("validate emilId: \(testStr)")

let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"

var emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)

var result = emailTest?.evaluateWithObject(testStr)

return result!

}
```

Use of Email-validation:

```
   if isValidEmail(textField.text)
  {
      println("Validate EmailID")
  }
  else
  {
      println("invalide EmailID")
  }
```

more from this [Email & Phone Validation in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998409/email-phone-validation-in-swift/27998447#27998447)

Comment: i am new to ios started with swift. If it possible wit swift.It will be help full

Comment: Question is asked for Swift

Comment: how can i show alert with this above solution code??

Comment: And what is that `rdfsdsfsdfsd`??

Comment: @user5513630 It's string!!!

Comment: i am getting two error `` Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

Comment: ` Use of unresolved identifier 'countElements'

Comment: how can i show alert with this above solution code??

Comment: i try to call this method name `isValidEmail ()` inside my sign up button press method .But i am getting errro in declaring my method name insode my sign up buttpn presss method.How can i call like this format ` else  if () {}` like that

Comment: `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call`

Answer (score 0):

this should be working fine

```
   func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
            let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
            let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
            let result = emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
            return result
        }
```

usage:

```
if isValidEmail("xxxx@gmail.com"){
//email is valid
}
```

Comment: False. The following emails are valid and this test says that it is invalid
`j@proseware.com9`, `js#internal@proseware.com` , `j_9@[129.126.118.1]`, ` js@proseware.com9` and the inverse for the following: `j.@server1.proseware.com`, `j..s@proseware.com` , `js@proseware..com` , `js@proseware..com`