# Validation of email in swift iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
class func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let range = testStr.rangeOfString(emailRegEx, options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
    let result = range != nil ? true : false
    return result
}
```

I use this function to validate email in my login form. I can't understand how to rise this event from my textfield.

Using like this

```
if(username.isEqualToString("") || [!LoginController, testStr == self.username]) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
    alertView.title = "Sign in Failed!"
    alertView.message = "Please enter valid username"
    alertView.delegate = self
    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
    alertView.show()
    return
}
```

But getting unresolved error at `teststr`. I am new to Swift. Can any body explain me how to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can validate email using a simple regex function which returns `true` if it's valid otherwise `false`

You can validate it when user hits *Done/Enter* on keyboard event, such as `editingDidEnd`. You can bind it from storyboard to class file like,

```
@IBAction func onPressDone(sender: UITextField){
    if txtEmaildAddress.text.isEmpty {
        println("enter email address") //prompt ALert or toast
    }
    else if self.validate(txtEmaildAddress.text) {
        println("Invalid email address") // prompt alert for invalid email
    }
}

func validate(YourEMailAddress: String) -> Bool {
    let REGEX: String
    REGEX = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", REGEX).evaluateWithObject(YourEMailAddress)
}
```

May help this method to validate easily.

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: Why `REGEX`? Why break every possible variable naming convention going? `YourEmailAddress`? `txtEmaildAddress`? Why not stick to a single convention?

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10**

For me, other answers were returning true if there are more then two dots after the domain name. I found this answer where it handles that condition properly.

```
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{1,4}$"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}
```

Happy Coding

Comment: Not working for someone123@tc.columbia.edu

Answer (score 2):

```
func isValidEmail(_ email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegEx = "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%\\&‘*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}" +
                     "~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\" +
                     "x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-" +
                     "z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5" +
                     "]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-" +
                     "9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21" +
                     "-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])"     
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: email)
}
```

**USAGE:**

`isValidEmail("name@mail.com")`
`output -> true`

`isValidEmail("name@mail")`
`output -> false`

Comment: What a monstruous regexp oO It gaves me an instant headache.

Answer (score 2):

**Apple Swift version 5.1.3 with Xcode 11.4**

```
extension String {
    func isEmail()->Bool {
            let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}"
            return  NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: self)
    }
}
```

**Use it :**

```
 if let _textfieldText = textField.text {
            if _textfieldText.isEmail() {
                print("Okay Email go ahead")
            }else{
                print("Enter a valid email address first.")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work for swift 4, 5

extension String {

```
var isValidEmail: Bool {
    let regex =  "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES%@", regex)
    return namePredicate.evaluate(with: self)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It have been written in many, many other threads like this, but since it's not in this one, I will be the one who said wisely the truth :

**DO NOT BOTHER TO VALIDATE MAILS WITH OVERCOMPLICATED (WRONG) REGULAR EXPRESSIONS**

Because even if your regexp is perfect and filter all possible email addresses without false negative (that will bother your users), your regexp will not prevent any user typo.

The only way to ensure that an email address is valide is to send a mail to it with a code or a validation mechanism. So, I would advice you to just check your mail address with something like `.+@.+` since all email addresses always have this form.

Then, send a mail to it to ensure that :

1. The email address exists
2. The email address is valid
3. The user is the email address owner (or, at least, can access it at this point in time)

Since an email address is not only a matter of syntax, if you have to work with valid ones, ensure they're not **only** syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

```
extension String {
    let emailFormat = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    let emailPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailFormat)
    return emailPredicate.evaluate(with: self)
}
```