# How to convert a JavaScript regex to Swift for email validation?

Tags: swift, regex

Hello I am new to `Swift`, and I am working on a project that requires `regex` validation for email validation, here's the code

```
static func validateEmail(string: String?) -> Style.ValidationResult {

    guard let string = string else {
        return .init(
            isValid: false,
            error: ValidationErrors.noEmail
        )
    }

    let format = "^[^!-/[-_{-~]*(?:[0-9A-Za-z](?:[0-9A-Za-z]+|([.])(?!\1)))*([^!-/[-_{-~]){1,256}@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25})+"
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", format)
    return .init(
        isValid: predicate.evaluate(with: string),
        error: ValidationErrors.noEmail
    )
}
```

When I build the app and actually test this part, it either returns `Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET` or simply cannot build.

I am aware that this is due to the escape character, but I have tried many times and still couldn't find out how to solve it, can anyone tell me the rules to conver JavaScript regex to Swift regex

Comment: At least make a [mcve] for the regex. Something like `[[]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an e-mail address in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471114/how-to-validate-an-e-mail-address-in-swift)

Comment: In javascript, did you use a `String` or `/.../` pattern? It seems some of the characters need escaping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- Use a "raw" string literal to avoid double escaping backslashes that form regex escapes (you have `\1` backreference and `\.` regex escape in the pattern), so use `let format = #"..."#`
- You need to escape square brackets inside character classes in an ICU regex pattern because `[` and `]` are both special (they are used to create character class intersections and unions).

Thus, you need to use

```
let format = #"^[^!-/\[-_{-~]*(?:[0-9A-Za-z](?:[0-9A-Za-z]+|(\.)(?!\1)))*([^!-/\[-_{-~]){1,256}@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25})+"#
```