# Email validation in swift

Tags: swift, regex

I found this code in google:

```
func isEmail(email: String) -> Bool {
    let emailRegx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
     
     let emailTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegx)
     
     return emailTest.evaluate(with: email)
    }
```

but I want to change the **emailRegx** to ensure that the first two characters in an email address can not be a number or symbols

Comment: `the first two characters in an email address can not be a number or symbols`, can you provide an example of how a email address should look like to pass the check (and how it shouldn't)? it's not clear what an email needs to start with if neither number nor symbol is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for adding additional information. if you combine your added code with that from my answer, do you get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very specific and lacks details or some code that you have tried.
However, this is my take based on how I understood your issue:

```
import Foundation

var validMail = "foo@bar.com"
var invalidMail = "1foo@bar.com"

func validateFirstLetter(_ string: String) -> Bool {
    string.first?.isLetter == true
}

print( validateFirstLetter(validMail) )   // true
print( validateFirstLetter(invalidMail) ) // false
```

For proper email validation you will find many implementations with a simple google search. For example:
[How to validate an e-mail address in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25471114/921573)