# I am trying to validate an email field using Regex in Swift

Tags: swift, regex, forms, validation

I am simply trying to validate an email using an expression. I have created a Struct that I use for my form fields.

```
 let emailRegEx = "[A-ZO-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-zO-9.-J+|l.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"
    var isEmailValid: Bool {
        !email.isEmpty &&
        if email.ranges(of: emailRegEx, options: .regularExpression) == nil {
            return self
        }
    }
```

It keeps throwing this error...Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'regularExpression', and Expected expression after operator, lastly Extra argument 'options' in call.

Comment: Cannot use instance member 'email' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available...This was the response I just got.

Comment: show us the complete code you are using, including how you declare `email` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` is in the wrong place, and `.ranges` should be `.range`.

Assuming your `emailRegEx` is correct, try this:

```
var isEmailValid: Bool = !email.isEmpty && (email.range(of: emailRegEx, options: .regularExpression) != nil)
```

Using a computed var, use this:

```
var isEmailValid: Bool {
    !email.isEmpty && (email.range(of: emailRegEx, options: .regularExpression) != nil)
}
```

You could also try this regex for email:

```
let emailRegEx = #"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$"#
```

Or

```
let emailRegEx = #"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$"#
```

See also this SO post: [How to validate an e-mail address in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471114/how-to-validate-an-e-mail-address-in-swift)

Comment: That was perfect minus one thing...it validates after just on character after the . could it be tweaked to include at least two?

Comment: You'll have to do a quick search on the net, for regex validating emails, there are plenty. I'm sure you will find something for your purpose. Updated my answer.

Comment: I have been but it seems they are breaking things. The one you gave as a modification was awesome, however it is validating before the dot and then again after.

Comment: see my update, with the SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471114/how-to-validate-an-e-mail-address-in-swift

Comment: ^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$

This is the golden egg!